# woocommerce REST API products by attributes filter not working iOS

Tags: ios, rest, filter, woocommerce

**I am using legacy V3 API version and woocommerce 2.6.4.I could filter category by "filter[category]"="Chair" But I could not filter using pa_* filter .I send parameter as "filter[pa_color]"= black;But I could not filter products based on color and returning complete products This is the request I am sending**

```
let client = AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient.init(baseURL: NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/wc-api/v3/"), key: "ck_xxx",secret: "cs_yyy")
   let  parameter = ["filter[pa_color]":"black"]

client.getPath("products", parameters: parameter, success: { (operation, responseObject) in....
```

please help if there is any filter in woocommerce for filtering based attributes..

Comment: hey Dinesh, is it working for you?